# Как выполнить php скрипт и записать его результат в файл?

Tags: php

Как выполнить php скрипт и записать его результат в файл?

Comment: $res = include_ones();  или ob_start();  include_ones();  $res = ob_get_clean(); и записать в файл.

Comment: больше подробностей,  а то ответят `php script.php > out.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
php script.php | tee log.txt
```

Проверил работает. Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php тут написано как можно на файлу добавить запись